# Dots in equation environment not appearing

Tags: equations

When I enter a number, for instance 10.2 in either an `equation` environment or within `$...$`, the dot is not appearing and instead I get an empty space. So for instance, I've typed:

```
$d_p = 5.12 \cdot 10^{-4} m$.
```

and what I get is: 5 12·10−4m.

I'm using a template, so there are many packages. For math and symbols I'm using the following:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{trfsigns}                                                
\usepackage{textcomp}                                               
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[integrals]{wasysym} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{ziffer}                                                 
\usepackage{dsfont}                                                 
\usepackage{upgreek}
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Even looking into the chrystal ball of wisdom does not reveal an answer unless you provide your document.

Comment: You have a hungry dot eater in your computer. And seriously: please prepare a MWE, so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer hah sorry guys, kinda new to this. I've added some more details, but not sure if it's enough?

Comment: Hi egil137 welcome to the site: Please read [this post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and do your best to follow the advice. Construct the MWE and see if the problem is still there. If you add `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} $d_p = 5.12 \cdot 10^{-4} m$. \end{document}` to your MWE you've provided and the problem goes away, then it's not enough. P.S.: Seems like it is enough

Comment: Well, simply by commenting out lines in your preamble it's the `ziffer` package that's doing it, I can tell you that. And this is precisely what `ziffer` is there to do: [click](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ziffer?lang=en) if you don't want that behaviour, why are you using the package?

Comment: @egil137: You should use `\SI{5.12d-4}{\meter}` rather (requires `siunitx` package).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is the `ziffer` package, which exists precisely to achieve this behaviour:

> The pack­age mod­i­fies the be­haviour of char­ac­ters in maths mode so that:
>   ‘.’ is used as a one-thou­sand sep­a­ra­tor (as is com­mon in Ger­many)
>   ‘,’ is used as a dec­i­mal sep­a­ra­tor (as is com­mon in Ger­many)
>   ‘--’ is rep­re­sented with spac­ing as ap­pro­pri­ate to such con­structs as ‘1.000,--’.
>
> https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ziffer?lang=en

You can see this working if you modify your example:

```
$d_p = 5,12 \cdot 10^{-4} m$.
```

[image]

So the `.` is being used to provide a small space to separate the thousands.

```
$d_p = 5.120.000$.
```

[image]

This is what `ziffer` is for, if you do not want this behaviour, you should not load the package.

In other news, if d_p is a length in metres, you should consider using the `siunitx` package to typeset it. The metres sign should never be italic and it needs to be separated from the value:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$d_p = \SI{5.12d-4}{\metre}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `ziffer` is a package that should not used at all, in my point of view

Comment: Many thanks! I will definitely get rid of that package.